# Color saturation issue with Ubuntu 22.04 (and lower versions) + Samsung Smart TV

Tags: kubuntu, display, amd-graphics, colors, samsung

I'm having some display issues with the next software and hardware combinations:

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04 (and other versions of Ubuntu)
- Graphics card: AMD Radeon RX 5500 XT
- Screen: Samsung UE32N4300

All colors look very saturated, specially yellows and greens. This is a huge problem for me because I'm a web developer and I need a good color fidelity.

There aren't display problems when using Windows 10 instead of Ubuntu, nor using another older Samsung screen I've got (funny thing: when I connect both screens at the same time when using Ubuntu, only the image in the older one looks perfectly). I don't know if the graphics card model has something to do with this issue.

I've tried changing the image settings on my screen, but since it's a smart TV the options are very very limited. I also tried changing the color settings on Ubuntu and installing the graphics' drivers. Lastly, I tried some workarounds, such as switching audio to HDMI port or installing 4.13 kernel. None of this worked.

Currently I'm using Kubuntu 22.04 LTS, but I also tried with Ubuntu and Kubuntu 20.04 and 21.04.

Can anyone give me a clue about all this? Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405904/ubuntu-22-04-shows-wrong-colors

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on solving this. I couldn't change the color profiles (from Kubuntu), and changing the gamma values was useless. Finally, I just changed the screen for another one and now everything is OK.

Thanks for your help